# Highcharts push chart to left of subtitle

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to push my highchart over to the left when the subtitle is right aligned.

For example, if a legend is added to the right, it correctly pushes the chart over:

http://jsfiddle.net/o2cceu96/5/

[image: alignment working]

but with subtitle it doesn't:

[image: alignment not working]

regardless if `floating: false` is set or not.

Using:

```
spacingRight: 50
```

Won't work either as it'll push all content (including title and subtitle) over:

http://jsfiddle.net/o2cceu96/9/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's just a case of adding `marginRight` instead:

```
marginRight: 50
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o2cceu96/10/